# convert int values to datetime in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to convert  the int values of a year, month and day in a datetime using sql server.

actually i' am using this

```
DECLARE @MONTH INT
DECLARE @YEAR INT
DECLARE @DAY  INT
DECLARE @MAXDATE DATETIME
DECLARE @MINDATE DATETIME

SET @MONTH=12
SET @YEAR=2010
SET @DAY=1


SET @MINDATE=CONVERT(DATE,CAST (@YEAR AS VARCHAR)+ RIGHT ('0'+ CAST (@MONTH AS VARCHAR),2) + RIGHT ('0'+ CAST (@DAY AS VARCHAR),2))

SELECT @MINDATE
```

and works ok, but i'm wondering if exist a better way to convert these values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be a little simpler:

```
select dateadd(month,(@YEAR-1900)* 12 + @MONTH - 1,0) + (@DAY-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you definitely have the right way to do this.  You're already padding the zeros for single digit months and dates; your solution will work well and is not untidy.

The only other way would be to being with some arbitrary date, and 'add' years, months and days to that starting point.  However this is not a great plan, because you would need to start at 31 December, 0 AD by my reckoning.  That makes less sense than simply parsing the components, as you are currently doing.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by 'better way', you may find different answers acceptable.
For example, converting from a string could be simpler (and thus better) than how it is done in your script. Like this:

```
SET @MINDATE = CAST(@YEAR AS varchar) + '-' +
               CAST(@MONTH AS varchar) + '-' +
               CAST(@DAY AS varchar)
```

That is, if your variable is `datetime`, the conversion will be implicit, so no need to use `CONVERT`. The format chosen here is `YYYY-MM-DD`, or rather `YYYY-M-D`, which is, as far as I know, acceptable for implicit conversion regardless of locale settings.

EDIT: The format you've chosen, `YYYYMMDD`, is locale independent too, if I'm not mistaken. My point was only that it required a more complex expression to build the proper string from integers, which seemed to inconvenience you.

Answer (score 0):

Untill i know there´s no way con convert it with a built in function.
If it´s possible to declare the year, month anda day as varchar, it can be easier:

```
SET DATEFORMAT YMD;
SET @MAXDATE = @YEAR+'/'+@MONTH+'/'+@DAY
SELECT @MAXDATE
```

Comment: Are you **sure** this would work on a SQL Server with e.g. "German" date format activated?? I highly doubt it - if you do something like this (string concatenation), then **please**: use the ISO-8601 format! `YYYYMMDD` - that'll work on any system, with any language setting...