# Convert multiple columns (year,month,day) to a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-view

I've got a few columns that I'm trying to convert to one, but I'm having some issues here.

The problem is that the Month or day can be single digit, and I keep losing that `0`.

I'm trying it on a view first before I do the conversion, but can't even get the three columns to give a string like this `20090517`.

Any ideas? `CAST` and `RIGHT` doesn't seem to be doing it for me.

Comment: What version of SQL Server please? Also don't need to put the tag "SQL Server" into the title. We know it's SQL Server. Because of the tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert int values to datetime in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847181/convert-int-values-to-datetime-in-sql-server)

Comment: using 2008 (but testing locally on)

Comment: @AaronBertrand - thanks, `dateadd(month,(@YEAR-1900)* 12 + @MONTH - 1,0) + (@DAY-1)` worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively

```
DECLARE @YEAR int
DECLARE @MONTH int
DECLARE @DAY int

SET @YEAR = 2013
SET @MONTH = 5
SET @DAY = 20

SELECT RIGHT('0000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Year),4) + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Month),2) + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Day),2)
```

Gives

```
20130520
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use DATEADD

```
DECLARE @YEAR int
DECLARE @MONTH int
DECLARE @DAY int

SET @YEAR = 2013
SET @MONTH = 5
SET @DAY = 20


SELECT CONVERT(DATE,
 DATEADD(yy, @YEAR -1900, DATEADD(mm, @MONTH -1 ,DATEADD(dd, @DAY -1, 0))))
```

Result is 2013-05-20

You can replace the variables in the SELECT command with the ones in your table.

Comment: Please don't use lazy shorthand like `yy` and `mm` - if you mean `YEAR`, type `YEAR`. Here's why: `SELECT DATEPART(Y, GETDATE());` - bet it doesn't yield what you'd think it would on first glance.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

`dateadd(month,(@YEAR-1900)* 12 + @MONTH - 1,0) + (@DAY-1)`